# How to add realtime timestamp column in spark DF while writing from kafka to db using spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

How to add realtime timestamp column in spark DF while writing from kafka to db using spark structured streaming?    i want exact timestamp when particular row was written into DB.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
df.withColumn("sourceFile", F.current_timestamp()) \
    .write
    .format("your database")
    .mode("overwrite")
```

Comment: it returns same timestamp for all the rows in the dataframe, if spark job was writing for 2 hours, i want different timestamp for each row ranging between those 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

Add `DEFAULT` timestamp `NOW()` value to the the database table row/record schema. Spark cannot create an exact timestamp when database was actually written, only when executor got a batch for the database writer